# Is $1/5+1/7+1/11+1/13+1/17+1/19+\cdots$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am struggling to calculate $$\dfrac 15+\dfrac 17+\dfrac 1{11}+\dfrac 1{13}+\dfrac 1{17}+\dfrac 1{19}+\cdots$$

The denominator is 6k - 1 and 6k + 1, k is pos integer from 1 to infinity.
Can somebody give me any hint if it is convergent, and if yes, what is the value at infinity? 
If divergent, why?

As it includes all primes in the demoninator, plus all non primes with 6k - 1 and 6k + 1 should it suggest that it is divergent?

Comment: What's the general term of the sequence?

Comment: The denominator is 6k - 1 and 6k + 1,  k is pos integer from 1 to infinity.

Comment: $6k \pm 1 \le 7k$, therefore ... ?

Comment: @MartinR Much easier than my approach, since we only need the divergence of the harmonic series.

Comment: Thanks. In addition, at which k becomes the sum greater than 1?

Comment: A nice additional question : Can the partial sum ever be an integer ?

Comment: @Tilsight: The asymptotics of the partial sums of the harmonic series are well-known, look up “harmonic numbers.” They grow $\sim \ln (n)$.

Comment: Thanks, guys, you gave me great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked for a hint, so here it is: $$\frac{1}{6k \pm 1} \ge \frac{1}{7k}$$ for all positive integers $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Since among the denominators , there are all the primes greater than $3$ and since the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges to $\infty$, this is also the case with the given sum.

Comment: Thanks. In addition,  can we see,  at which k is the sum greater than 1?

Comment: According to my calculation (with simple brute force), we exceed $1$ with the summand $\frac{1}{65}$

Comment: Thanks, Peter,for your help.